# Is it secure to store JSON-formatted data in a database

Tags: php, json, database

I'm trying to store JSON data in a database as I think that it will be more efficient to store it in a database rather than storing it in JSON files.

I'm using this to parse the data as a JSON object:

```
$json_data_decoded = json_decode($json_data_found, true);
if(!empty($json_data_decoded)){
    foreach($json_data_decoded as $key => $data){
         // Do something with this data
    }
}
```

Of course it works OK but I'm worried about storing this sort of data in the database as it will take the user inputs and encode it then store it in the database. **So what is better and more secure way of storing the data in a JSON file or in the database?**

**Edit:**
I'm using a MySQL database and if I choose to use the database option I will have to store the JSON object in only one field.

Comment: In the database is fine, providing the column supports the format the json string is encoded too.  Its sometimes even better than storing serialized strings, but thats more of a serialization of multi-byte characters issue.

Comment: SQL?: Just make sure you don't accidentally use user data to construct database statements (use prepared statements with place-holders). And check the input length if necessary (if you have to deal with limited types). And adhere to Flosculus comment.

Comment: As long as you use prepared statments it should be ok to put it in. Just be careful for XSS attacks though when echoing it out to the page.

Comment: What do you mean, "secure"? JSON is just text. You treat it like any other text you're stuffing into the database. Just because it's JSON doesn't make it special in any way, really - it is just text. But if you need to access any components of a JSON-encoded data structure, then don't use json. Unless you're on a DB that directly supports json, you'll be limited to string operations for retrieving that data, and that can be HIGHLY inefficient.

Comment: JSON is just a string, if it is escaped properly like any other string before inserting it in your database it will be ok.

Comment: A MongoDB database is basically JSON, worth a look if your are working on a new project.

Comment: Check out postgres if you're not using it already, it supports json natively and in the future will allow you to index it and even perform queries on the json data quickly.

Comment: Ok buddies I got it. I'm going to store it in a MySQL database. The idea here is that I will have only one field to store the whole data, so I wanted to be sure. But you are right buddies it is just a text I just have to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

so I am a python developer and I use Django to make my projects. I have stored json data in JSONField, which is a model field to store JSON-encoded data.

With a quick Google search I got this, "***Unlike other formats, JSON is human-readable text. PostgreSQL supports native JSON data type since version 9.2.***". So most common databases should allow storing JSON data.

If your usecase contains unstructured Data then you should go for a document type database like MongoDB which stores data in BSON format (Binary JSON) which is somewhat similar to JSON and feasible option for unstructured data storage and manipulation.

According to me, you can use JSON-encoded data in databases if they comes with a perfect fit for your use case and don't hold any sensitive data like access tokens, password, API secret key, etc. Because for sensitive data, hashing (eg. bcrypt) is prefered as a good practise.

Thankyou!